# How can I find all projects with a specific file sorted by number of stars

Tags: github

I'd like to be able to for example.
Find the project with the most starts that has a package.json
Find the project with the most starts that has a travis.yml
Find the projects with the most stars written in swift that have a podfile.

Can I do this via the API or the website?